# On changing a product attribute updating other attribute value of the product in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have one product attribute as `percentage_discount` for wholesale price and another attribute as `wholesaleprice`.

I want to update the `wholesaleprice` every time I am making changes in `percentage_discount` attribute.

Do we have any event in magento which triggers only on changing/updating the particular attribute not for other attribute changes for the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe attributes get their own specific events.  The simplest solution is probably observing `catalog_product_attribute_update_before`, which gets passed an array of the attribute(s) (`attributes_data`) and product(s) (`product_ids`) updated.  Then you can just check if `percentage_discount` is set in `attributes_data`, if it is that means it's being changed so you can load the product(s) from `product_ids` and set their new `wholesaleprice`.